# How to really set up a Rails 4.2 application in a subdirectory? Using nginx and puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, puma

First I have to say that I tried it hard for a long time.
I have a application that's in /home/deploy/app/myapp and want to deploy it to be accessed in http://myurl.com/myapp because I want to have many others over the same domain name.

The problem is that Rails default configuration is not working like it should. Some say that I should just put a configuration in application.rb or in production.rb or a environment variable (RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT) [ http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#deploy-to-a-subdirectory-relative-url-root ]. But I keep getting 404. The only way that it worked was when I put this in the routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 scope '/myapp' || '/' do
  root 'home#index'
 end
end
```

It fells wrong. The "config.relative_url_root" should work. Don't it?

And another thing is that the assets is still wrong. I can't get them right. What should I do?

My NGINX config is:

```
upstream myapp {
  server unix:///home/deploy/apps/myapp/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name myapp;
  keepalive_timeout 5;
  access_log /home/deploy/apps/myapp/current/log/production.access.log;
  error_log /home/deploy/apps/myapp/current/log/production.error.log info;

  if (-f $document_root/maintenance.html) {
    rewrite  ^(.*)$  /maintenance.html last;
    break;
  }

  location @myapp {
    proxy_pass http://myapp;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }

  location /myapp {
    alias /home/deploy/apps/myapp/current/public;
    try_files $uri @myapp;
  }
}
```

How can I fix the assets in a way that NGINX server it also?

Thank you!

Comment: have u fix it ? thanks

Comment: to fix the assets a put this in application.rb, but as I said it doesnt feel right.
  config.relative_url_root = '/oraculo'
    config.root_directory = '/oraculo'

Comment: What the hell is that it didn't generate the irk with the prefix even I put the setting in the application config file